# CSV remove column without header name

Tags: powershell

I'm having trouble to select specific column from CSV file. I need to select only 2 column :

1002     2019-02-01 00:03:07

Here is my example:

```
(Get-Content c:\Users\file.csv)  -replace ',', "`t" -replace '/', '-'  | 
  foreach { $_ + "`t 1 `t 255 `t 1 `t 0" } | 
  Select -Skip 1 | 
  Set-Content C:\Users\outfile.csv
```

My Output right now:

```
1002    Hafiz   New Organization    9-6-2019 13:57  Check In    'Main1_Door1_Entrance Card Reader1  Main1_Door1_Entrance Card Reader1    1   255     1   0
1002    Hafiz   New Organization    9-6-2019 15:44  Check In    'Main1_Door1_Entrance Card Reader1  Main1_Door1_Entrance Card Reader1    1   255     1   0
```

End Result:

```
 3006   2019-02-01 00:03:07     1   255 1   0
 1005   2019-02-01 06:44:31     1   255 1   0
```

Comment: please, add the 1st three or four lines of your _input_ CSV file, and how you want those lines to look in your output. right now, you have not provided enuf info to make a judgement on what would work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has a built-in `Import-Csv` command. This avoids the need to manually parse CSV files yourself. You could do something like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path c:\Users\file.csv | Select-Object -Property Column1, Column2
```